# Automapper: Conditional mapping based on Source object and ResolutionContext

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to make a conditional mapping based on both the source object and ResolutionContext. Here is my code:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt =>
        {
            opt.Condition(context=>
                {
                    bool condition1 = (bool)context.Options.Items["Condition"];
                    bool condition2 = SomeFunction(context.SourceValue);
                    return !(condition1 && !condition2);
                });
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value);
        });
```

Unfortunately, this breaks because `context.SourceValue` is returning a `String` (not a `SourceType`). I thought that `context.SourceValue` returned the source object, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there any way to do conditional mapping based on both the ResolutionContext and the Source object?

Comment: What is the type of SourceType.Value?

Comment: So you want to only map SourceType.Value to DestinationType.Value based on a condition that takes the whole SourceType object as input?

Comment: Is `context.Options.Items["Condition"]` relevant? What would it contain?

Comment: `context.Options.Items["Condition"]` provides context for the mapping. In this case, I'm using it to toggle a level of privacy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.SourceValue` returns the member currently being converted, which in this case is `SourceType.Value` (which I guess is a string).

To obtain the `SourceType` object, use the following:

```
SourceType source_object = (SourceType)context.Parent.SourceValue;
```

Comment: For those pulling their hair out: AutoMapper 5 removed the context.Parent property